# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Confusion

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm new to python and am trying to write a code that would deal poker hands and check for pat flushes.  Below is my code and the shell when I try to run it.  According to my professor this should return `True` if there is only one suit in the hand, i.e., only one entry in the set "suits" and `False` otherwise, but I keep getting this error message.  Can someone help explain this to me?

```
from random import *

suits = {'H','C','D','S'}   #hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades
ranks = {'a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','j','q','k'}  #card values
deck = [r +s for r in ranks for s in suits]
hand = []

def deal (n):
    '''deals n hands'''

    for n in range (0,n):
        hand = sample (deck,5)

        for x in hand:
            deck.remove (x)

        print (hand)

def is_flush (hand):
    '''checks for pat flush hands'''
    suits = {c[-1] for c in hand}
    return len(suits) == 1

RUN

>>> is_flush (5)

['10S', 'qD', '8H', '8D', '3S']
['5C', 'jC', 'kS', '4C', '2H']
['2S', '7C', '7H', '7S', '9S']
['8C', '8S', 'aH', '5S', '2D']
['9D', '6S', '4D', 'qS', '9H']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    is_flush (5)

  File "K:/stalter_3.py", line 19, in is_flush
    suits = {c[-1] for c in hand}

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

>>>
```

Comment: you might want to debug print `hand` prior to that line, just in case. I suspect this is a side-effect problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `is_flush(5)`. If I understand you correctly, then that value 5 is the variable `hand` which you are trying to iterate through (as if it were a hand) in `c[-1] for c in hand`, but you can't iterate an integer. The reason I'm confused is I would expect it to say that it's an IntType, not a NoneType.

Comment: I've also tried to do is_flush (deal(5)) to see if I needed it to call the deal function

Comment: That would be better, but note that `deal` doesn't return the hand! you need to add `return hand` as the last line of `deal`, and call it like you said `is_flush(deal(5))`.